# morph images effect in Processing

Tags: java, processing, pixel, morphing

I would like to build a kind of image morphing tool in Processing. Similar to what you can see in this link:

https://giphy.com/gifs/painting-morph-oil-c8ygOpL64UDuw

My first step to achieve this was to build a two-dimensional grid of pixels. The pixels are filled with colour. The fill colour is created by reading colour from an image (PImage img1;) with the get(); function. This is how I recreated an image with my pixels.  In the second step, I thought I would use the lerp(); function to give the respective pixels the colour of a second image (PImage img2;) - I thought this would create the desired morph effect. But I was wrong! The whole thing works - but the effect is only that a fade-in takes place between the two images. And no morphing. What exactly happens to pixels while this morph effect? How could I recreate it in Processing?

```
float pixel;
float pixelsize;
PImage img1;
PImage img2;
float counter;

void setup() {
  size(1080, 1080);
  pixel = 100;
  pixelsize = width/pixel;
  noStroke();
  img1 = loadImage("0.jpg");
  img2 = loadImage("1.jpg");
  counter = 0;
}


void draw() {
  background(255);

  for (int y = 0; y < pixel; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < pixel; x++) {
      color c1 = img1.get(int(pixelsize*x), int(pixelsize*y));
      color c2 = img2.get(int(pixelsize*x), int(pixelsize*y));

      color from = c1;
      color to = c2;
      color interA = lerpColor(from, to, counter);

      pushMatrix();
      translate(pixelsize*x, pixelsize*y);
      fill(interA);
      rect(0, 0, pixelsize, pixelsize);
      popMatrix();
    }
  }
  counter= counter + 0.01;
}
```

Comment: I have two morphing scripts that are bash shell scripts calling Imagemagick (shapemorph and shapemorph2) on my web site at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/ that use a shepards warp to do the distortion and fades. The first script takes one control point pair and the second script permits any number of control point pairs between the two input images for alignment.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed it is not a straight forward task.

You're approach is not a bad start: it would result in a nice crossfade between the two images.

Bare in mind `get()` can be costly on the CPU.
You can however use the [`pixels[]`](https://processing.org/reference/pixels.html):

```java
PImage img1;
PImage img2;
// transition image
PImage imgT;

void setup() {
  size(1080, 1080);
  
  img1 = loadImage("0.jpg");
  img2 = loadImage("1.jpg");
  // copy the 1st image (copies width/height as well)
  imgT = img1.get();
}


void draw() {
  background(255);
  // map transition amount to mouse X position
  float t = map(mouseX, 0, width, 0.0, 1.0);
  
  // make all pixels readable
  imgT.loadPixels();
  // lerp each pixel
  for(int i = 0 ; i < imgT.pixels.length; i++){
    imgT.pixels[i] = lerpColor(img1.pixels[i], img2.pixels[i], t);
  }
  // update all pixels in one go
  imgT.updatePixels();
  
  // display result
  image(imgT, 0, 0);
}
```

Implementing a full morph image is non-trivial.
I can recomend two options to make use of existing algorithms, however these options are also not beginner friendly:

1. [ImageMagick implements shepards distortion](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#shepards) and there is a java library that interfaces with imagemagick: [im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/). Note that you'd need to download the precompiled java library and drop the .jar file on top of your sketch and processing the output might take time: probably not feasible for realtime (however it should be possible to save individual frames to disk and assemble them as a gif/movie/etc.)
2. Using OpenCV: there's an [OpenCV Face Morph](https://learnopencv.com/face-morph-using-opencv-cpp-python/) tutorial with source code in c++ or [Python](https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/FaceMorph/faceMorph.py) and there is a Processing OpenCV library. It would be a matter of porting the c++/Python OpenCV calls to the Java OpenCV API.

Comment: Imagemagick already has a morph method, but it is just a fade.

Comment: that is correct, however it's not the morph functionality I was pointing to, but [shepards distortion](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#shepards) which is pretty close to what Cyrill was asking

Comment: See my comment above about my scripts which use shepards distortion

Comment: that's really cool! it might mean forking/updating `im4java` to tap into that, otherwise manually spawning a process from Processing via [`exec()`](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#exec-java.lang.String...-) should (famous last words) work :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I will work on in and keep you updated!